# Best database data structure for a many to many tree, based on item availability

Tags: database-design, tree, hierarchical-data

I'm currently developping a Website based on MySQL, but switching to another database is not a problem if necessary (like for CTE or so).

I'm looking for the best database data structure (and if possible some SQL snippets) to handle my current project, which is as follow:

- A product can be made of other products (recursively), so products have to be designed in a tree-oriented architecture.
- A product may be used for the fabrication of many products. That is where something like the Nested Set architecture won't work, because a node can be a children and a parent of many nodes, which does not seem possible using NestedSet.
- A product has a quantity available for each day, but only if it is a "leaf" (it is not made from another product). Otherwise its quantity will depend on the quantity of its direct children (and so on, until the recursion reaches the leaves). So products may be linked to a table "availability", which contains "product_id", "date" and "quantity".

The "tree" structure of the products is quite stable, so the speed of Update/Insert/Delete queries does not really matters.

The final goal is to be able to retrieve in a SELECT query as fast as possible, the list of all the products that are available between two dates specified.

This means that:

- 1) If the product is not made of another one, it is available if quantity > 0 for each day between the two dates.
- 2) If the product is made of other ones, it is avalailable only if (1) is true for all its children. If the direct children are not "leaf", they will not have quantity, so a recursion for (2) will happened until it reaches the final leaves.

By the way, in a real case scenario, my products will never have more than 5 level of depth. Maybe it would be a good (but very ugly) idea to store all the parent ID's in separate columns.

Comment: A french word meaning "database management system", I edited my post to translate it, thought It was an english word.

Comment: So, a quantity is not a property of product, it's a property of a **combination** of product and date, correct?

Comment: Yes, there is a separate table "availability" which contains three fields: date, product_id, and quantity. I edited my post.

Comment: A product is only available "between two dates" if it is available *on each and every date* in the interval - is that correct?  In other words, if there is a single day in the interval for which the product is unavailable, it is not returned by the query (and thereby deemed unavailable for the whole interval)?  Is the interval [open or closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology)?

Comment: Yes, a product will be available between dates A and D, only if it is available for each day (ex: A,B,C,D). A and D are included in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data structure you describe is *not* a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) (which requires that every node has exactly one parent, except the root which has no parent): rather, it is a more general [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph):

[image: Directed Acyclic Graph]

Other RDBMS have native support for hierarchical data and recursive queries, whereas MySQL does not; instead a good general relational model for storing such data in MySQL is to create a table of the graph's [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).  Using `//` as the statement delimiter:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products (
  SKU         SERIAL                COMMENT 'Stock-Keeping Unit code',
  Name        VARCHAR(15)           COMMENT 'Product name',
  Description VARCHAR(255)          COMMENT 'Descriptive text',
  Price       DECIMAL(6,2)          COMMENT 'Selling price',
  isAtomic    BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE COMMENT 'Flag indicating atomicity'
)
  ENGINE  = InnoDB,
  COMMENT = 'Properties relating to each product'
//

CREATE TABLE ProductComponents (
  SKU          BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Stock-Keeping Unit Code',
  ComponentSKU BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'SKU of comprised component',
  PRIMARY KEY (SKU, ComponentSKU),
  INDEX       (ComponentSKU, SKU),
  FOREIGN KEY (         SKU) REFERENCES Products (SKU),
  FOREIGN KEY (ComponentSKU) REFERENCES Products (SKU)
)
  ENGINE  = InnoDB,
  COMMENT = 'Transitive closure of the product DAG'
//
```

One can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) to enforce atomicity in the latter table:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ins_atomic BEFORE INSERT ON ProductComponents
FOR EACH ROW IF
  NEW.SKU <> NEW.ComponentSKU
  AND (SELECT isAtomic FROM Products WHERE SKU = NEW.SKU)
THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET
    MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Atomic product cannot have a component'
  ;
END IF//

CREATE TRIGGER upd_atomic BEFORE UPDATE ON ProductComponents
FOR EACH ROW IF
  NEW.SKU <> NEW.ComponentSKU
  AND (SELECT isAtomic FROM Products WHERE SKU = NEW.SKU)
THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET
    MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Atomic product cannot have a component'
  ;
END IF//
```

You may also want a similar trigger that prevents incorrect updating of `Products.isAtomic`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER upd_prod BEFORE UPDATE ON Products
FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.isAtomic AND EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM ProductComponents WHERE SKU <> ComponentSKU AND SKU = NEW.SKU
) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET
    MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Atomic product cannot have a component'
  ;
END IF//
```

For the graph depicted above, your data would be as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO Products
  (SKU, isAtomic)
VALUES
  (  2, TRUE    ),
  (  3, FALSE   ),
  (  5, FALSE   ),
  (  7, FALSE   ),
  (  8, FALSE   ),
  (  9, TRUE    ),
  ( 10, TRUE    ),
  ( 11, FALSE   )
//

INSERT INTO ProductComponents
  (SKU, ComponentSKU)
VALUES
  (2,2),
  (3,3),   (3,8),   (3,9),   (3,10),
  (5,5),   (5,11),  (5,2),   (5,9),   (5,10),
  (7,7),   (7,8),   (7,9),   (7,11),  (7,2),   (7,10),
  (8,8),   (8,9),
  (9,9),
  (10,10),
  (11,11), (11,2),  (11,9),  (11,10)
//
```

Then you can store availability as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ProductAvailability (
  SKU      BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Stock-Keeping Unit Code',
  Date     DATE                     COMMENT 'Availability date',
  Quantity INT                      COMMENT 'Available quantity',
  PRIMARY KEY (SKU, Date),
  FOREIGN KEY (SKU) REFERENCES Products (SKU)
)
  ENGINE  = InnoDB,
  COMMENT = 'Available quantities'
//
```

Some test data for the above might be:

```sql
INSERT INTO ProductAvailability
  (SKU, Date        , Quantity)
VALUES
  (  2, '2012-12-13',     NULL),
  (  2, '2012-12-15',       15),
  (  9, '2012-12-13',      234),
  (  9, '2012-12-14',       46),
  (  9, '2012-12-15',        0),
  ( 10, '2012-12-13',        4),
  ( 10, '2012-12-14',        7),
  ( 10, '2012-12-15',        5)
//
```

And your query would be:

```sql
SELECT   p.*
FROM     Products p
    JOIN ProductComponents c USING (SKU)
    JOIN (
           SELECT   p.SKU AS ComponentSKU,
                    COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF(@end_date, @start_date) + 1 AS available
           FROM     Products p LEFT JOIN ProductAvailability a
                 ON a.SKU = p.SKU
                AND a.Quantity > 0
                AND a.Date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
           WHERE    p.isAtomic
           GROUP BY p.SKU
         ) q USING (ComponentSKU)
GROUP BY p.SKU
HAVING   NOT SUM(q.available = 0)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35852/1).

Comment: Looking through the links you shared, I can see that Graph can be easily handled using anything but MySql, with "connect by" or "with recursive". That can be a good starting point to handle what I called a tree, but the availability part still remains.

Comment: That seems perfect. Thank you very much for your help. I'll give you the bounty when available.